# Hibernate bug - Query.setTimeout not working as expected

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I am using Hibernate 3.6.

I am calling this method but it seems it has no effect.
`org.hibernate.Query.setTimeout`

So... I am creating a `Query` object and using it to call a MS SQL Server Stored Procedure.

In the procedure I intentionally added `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20';` in order to delay its execution. So the procedure takes >= 20 secs to run, that's for sure.

I set a timeout of 5 seconds in my hibernate `Query`.

See also:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setTimeout(int)

To my surprise, I get no error in my Java code after 5 secs are elapsed!
The Java code just keeps blocking there and waits for the stored procedure to complete?!?!?!

Why is that so?
Looks like an obvious bug to me.

What am I missing?

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.transform.Transformers;
import org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType;
import org.hibernate.type.NullableType;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateCallback;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

..... other imports ..... 

..... other code ..... 

public Boolean callStoredProcedureWithArguments2(final String spName, final Integer timeout, final Object... arguments) {
    return (Boolean) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            boolean success = false;
            try {
                StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder();
                sbQuery.append("EXEC " + spName + " ");
                int n = arguments == null ? 0 : arguments.length;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        sbQuery.append(",");
                    }
                    sbQuery.append(String.format(" :%s%d", "param", i));
                }
                Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sbQuery.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if (arguments[i] == null) {
                        query.setParameter(String.format("%s%d", "param", i), arguments[i]);
                    } else {
                        AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType tp = HibernateUtil.getHibernateType(arguments[i].getClass());
                        if (tp == null) {
                            query.setParameter(String.format("%s%d", "param", i), arguments[i]);
                        } else {
                            query.setParameter(String.format("%s%d", "param", i), arguments[i], tp);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (timeout != null){
                    query.setTimeout(timeout);
                }
                query.executeUpdate();
                success = true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logging.logError("Error while calling SP: " + spName + ".", ex);
                success = false;
            }
            return success;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If it's an "obvious bug" shouldn't you file a bug instead?

Comment: It's too obvious for me to believe, that's why I am asking here first.

Comment: Please share the code you are using for setting the timeout.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Done. The caller of this method is passing 5 for timeout. From the JavaDoc page of Query that's 5 secs, I understood. Note that this method has been working fine for a long time. All I added in it now (and I want this to work OK) is setting that timeout right before I call `executeUpdate`. But it seems to me the timeout has no effect.

Comment: Well, that's what I understood from the documentation. Sorry, I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Seems it's a bug in hibernate, that's all.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Where can one file a bug? Is the 3.x hibernate line still supported. maintained, etc.? I know the latest Hibernate version is 5.x, I think.

Comment: @peter.petrov I have to admit I don't know.

Comment: @peter.petrov were you able to resolve this issue? In the same situation.